# Remote JMeter save response data

Tags: jmeter

I created a project like this:
[image]

I want to check the http response data, so used "Summary Report" and "Save Response to file" listeners, and I ran this project in remote mode, found that neither "Summary report" or "Save Response to file" output file was empty. If I ran this project in standalone mode, the output files saved repose data OK.

Am I using the listeners in a wrong way, or these kind of response listeners not support in the remote mode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is due to JMeter's default slave-master results sending mode **StrippedBatch** which removes response data from successful samples, see [Using a different sample sender](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html#sendermode) chapter of the [Remote Testing](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html) User Manual chapter for detailed explanation of the available modes.

You can switch the mode via either adding the following line to *user.properties* file (located in JMeter's /bin folder)

```
mode=Standard
```

or pass it as a command-line argument to JMeter slave startup script as:

```
jmeter-server.bat -Jmode=Standard
```

See [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) guide for more information on different JMeter properties types and ways of setting them and [JMeter Distributed Testing Step-by-step](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.pdf) guide for other remote testing tips.

Comment: Thanks for your help, the standard mode works right now.